# Issue with injar parameter in Proguard using ant tasks

Tags: java, ant, obfuscation, proguard

I'm using proguard from ant (version 5.0 beta 2), when I try to add input jars (AKA injars) with filter (!META-INF/MANIFEST-MF) the parameter is converted to:

```
-injars '/path-to-my-file/myjar.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST-MF)'
```

Instead of

```
-injars /path-to-my-file/myjar.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST-MF)
```

So the filter `(!META-INF/MANIFEST-MF)` is ignored and an error is thrown trying to read the file "/path-to-my-file/myjar.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST-MF)"

My build.xml is similar to:

```
    <pathconvert property="other_injars" refid="injars">
        <mapper>
          <globmapper from="*.jar" to="*.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)" casesensitive="no"/>
        </mapper>
    </pathconvert>

    <!-- obfuscate and optimize by ProGuard -->
    <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="${proguard.home}/lib/proguard.jar" />
    <proguard configuration="${proguard.config.file}" >
        <injar refid="main_injar"/>
        <injar path="${other_injars}"/>
        <outjar path="${workdir}/${output.jar.file}"/>
        <libraryjar refid="third_parties" />
    </proguard>
```

My question is, How can I avoid the `'` character in the generated `injar` parameter value when I use a filter ?

I suppose that the proguard ant task is escaping the file path due to the character: `(` or `!`, but It shouldn't because actually, they are not part of the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ProGuard-style configuration, filters are specified between parentheses, after the file names:

```
-injars application.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
```

In Ant configuration, file names and filters are specified with separate attbutes:

```
<injar path="application.jar" filter="!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" />
```

So in this case, you shouldn't append the filter with parentheses to the file name.

Comment: It works, thanks. In the `injar` task definition in Proguard ant doc page, there is no "filter" attribute `<injar class_path />`

Comment: If you click on class_path in the Ant documentation, you'll go to the section "Class Path Attributes and Nested Elements", which explains the attributes.